# Изменение url в запросах компонента Angular

Tags: http, iframe, angular

В проекте используем Angular6.
Нужно сделать VNC view, для этого используем noVNC. Загрузка страницы происходит в iframe, Все хорошо когда браузер открыт в той же сети и имеет доступ к VNC серверу, т.е. запросы к серверу выглядят так - http://192.168.55.30:8888.
Но вот со внешки все не так радужно, т.к. доступа нет к VNC серверу. Поэтому нужно использовать прокси, но для его проксирования нужно все запросы http://192.168.55.30:8888 модифицировать во что то такое http://vnc/192.168.55.30:8888.

Суть вопроса, какими средствами сделать изменение url для всех запросов этого компонента.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Немного не то. При загрузке iframe src = http://vnc/192.168.55.30:8888, но сам подгружаемый iframe имеет свои методы, которые выполняются http://......, вот в эти запросы нужно отправить по адресу  http://vnc/.... Перехватчики http работают на все приложении, что мне не подходит, нужно как то сделать перехватчик в отдельном модуле.

Comment: тогда вам однозначно нужно проксировать все это дело через сервер, не нужно такими вещами грузить фронт, сервер это будет делать в разы быстрее

Comment: Ну так я и хочу через сервер, только серверу нужно путь указать отличный от дефолтного. Фронт должен просто в запросе модифицировать url